# Google Earth Plugin: first load static .kmz, then play tour .kmz?

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, kmz

Is there a way to have the Google Earth plugin do the following when the web page loads?

1. Display a static .kmz file, as in http://www.ppacg.org/tours/logo.html
2. Start a tour player .kmz, as in http://www.ppacg.org/tours/tabview.html?project=08-37

I can do either #1 or #2 above separately, but I can't figure out how to get them both to happen when the web page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply load both files using the [fetchKml](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/kml#fetchkml_and_parsekml) method in the [google.earth namespace](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace). You could then provide the logic to handle displaying the data and entering the tour in the callback parameter.

To play the tour you have to walk the Kml DOM looking for the [KmlTour](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_tour) object so that you can open it with the [GETourPlayer](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_tour_player). To do this is you can use the [earth utility library](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/) or alternatively you could use the [kmldomwalk.js](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/lib/kmldomwalk.js) script.

Something like the following java-script should work (although it is written here and is untested).

```
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi/"></script>
<script src="//earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/lib/kmldomwalk.js"></script>
<script>
google.load("earth", "1");

var ge = null;
var kml1= '//www.ppacg.org/tours/logo.html';
var kml2= '//www.ppacg.org/tours/tabview.html?project=08-37';
var tour = null; // so you can call pause, stop, etc globally...

function init() {
  // presumes you have a div with the id 'map3d'
  google.earth.createInstance("map3d", initCallback, function(e){alert(e);});
}

function initCallback(object) {
  ge = object;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
  // load your data 
  google.earth.fetchKml(ge, kml1, fetchKmlCallback);
  google.earth.fetchKml(ge, kml2 , fetchKmlCallback);
}

function fetchKmlCallback(object) {
  if (object) {
    // add the features to the plugin
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(object);
    // Walk the DOM looking for a KmlTour
    walkKmlDom(object, function() {
      if (this.getType() == 'KmlTour') {
        tour = this;
        ge.getTourPlayer().setTour(tour); // enter the tour
        return false; // stop the DOM walk here.
      }
    });
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
     alert('Bad or null KML.');
    }, 0);
  }
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
</script>
```

Also take a look at these examples of using [fetchkml](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/kml-fetch-interactive.html) and [playing tours](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/tour-player.html) if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fraser, that worked perfectly! Here is the updated web page: http://www.ppacg.org/tours/tabview.html?project=08-37